# Update MySql table related record relationship without lost data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have three MySql table

category table:

```
id        link_id     category_id
--------------------------------------
1          5           10
2          6           12
3          5           12
```

Link table:

```
link_id    link_title         link_url        website_id
-------------------------------------------------------
5          title            test.com/test         1
6          title2           test.com/test2        1
7          title3           link.com/linklist     2
```

Website table:

```
website_id      url
-----------------------------
1               test.com
2               link.com
```

now I need to change category table link_id to website_id
like this

```
id        link_id(/website_id)     category_id
--------------------------------------
1          1                    10
2          2                    12
3          1                    12
```

Is this possible using MySql update query

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why is the category with the `Id` = 3 has `link_id(/website_id)` = 2 where that `link_id` for this category has no entries in the `link` table. Why it is 2??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can join both tables,

```
UPDATE  category a
        INNER JOIN link b
            ON a.link_id = b.link_ID
SET     a.link_ID = b.website_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d0fd/1)

Comment: *PS: are you sure that you desired results are correct? because I find it wrong due to `link_id`*

Answer (score 0):

Try this query but make sure you have backup before doing this.

```
UPDATE category AS c
  INNER JOIN Link AS l
    ON l.link_id = c.link_id
SET c.link_id = l.website_id
```

Comment: what happens here is when `category` has record which don't have match on table `Link`, the result value of `category.link_id` will be *null*

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE category
SET link_id = website_id FROM Link L
WHERE L.link_id = category.link_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ??

```
update catagory a
set a.link_id = (
  select b.website_id from link b
  inner join website c on b.website_id = c.website_id
    where a.link_id= b.link_id)
```